# Cannot show result in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I created 2 tables in MySQL Workbench by using code:

```
create table mobile(id int, Name char(4), Type int, Amount int);

insert into mobile(id,Name,Type,Amount) Values (2,"iPad",1,1000);
insert into mobile(id,Name,Type,Amount) Values (3,"iPad",2,1000);
insert into mobile(id,Name,Type,Amount) Values (4,"iPod",6,1000);

create table objs(id int,Name char(4),price int);

insert into objs(id,Name,price) Values(2,"iPad",1000);
insert into objs(id,Name,price) Values(3,"iPad",900);
insert into objs(id,Name,price) Values(4,"iPod",400);
```

and `Leftjoin` them

```
select * FROM mobile LEFT JOIN objs on mobile.Name=objs.Name;
```

It succeed but no table came out

[image]

In cmd, it works well

[image]

So what's wrong with my workbench? What can I do if I want to see the table like what in cmd shows?

Screen shot of my SQL Workbench

[image]

___________________________________Edit_____________________________________

I close the window and opened it again...now the table comes out

But I still don't know what happened!!!!

Comment: Your results panel (where it shows tables) was probably hidden/collapsed